# How do I get other table information from linq ".include"

Tags: database, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to get information from Table1 as well as Table2 by using this....

```
Public Shared Function SelectDataByDateAndLastName(ByVal Date As Date, ByVal TxtBoxLastName As String)

    Dim TableItems As ObjectQuery(Of tblTable1) = From TableItem In tblTable1.Include("tblTable2")
                                                        Where TableItem.ItemDate = Date _
                                                        And tblTable2.LastName = TxtBoxLastName
    Return TableItems
```

But I get an error on tblTable2.LastName

```
Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference
```

Any idea on how to get the `LastName` info from Table2? Or am I not even using this right? Thank you!

Comment: Is this `Entity Framework`?

Comment: Yes, at least to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Well, you should know for sure, otherwise you're programming blindly. For one, you don't seem to know what `Include` is for. It's *not* for including any other table in your query. If this is all new to you (which is OK) you better do some tutorials on Entity Framework and LINQ. Learn about navigation properties and Include vs. joins, for instance.

Comment: You're right, I'm new to this. I will take your advice and learn more about Entity Framework and LINQ. It seems like I'm missing the knowledge on some key topics here. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I'd use the Join command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a navigation property - you access it like this:

```
Dim TableItems As ObjectQuery(Of tblTable1) = 
    From TableItem In tblTable1.Include("tblTable2")
    Where TableItem.tblTable2.LastName = TxtBoxLastName
```

Comment: I am getting an error `tblTable2 is not a member of Entities.tblTable1.`

Comment: Then you did not set up a foreign key relationship or this is not EF.

Comment: When you are creating the `DB` if you make a foreign key relationship between tables then `EF` makes a `Navigation Property` which will be on the originating table. All member of that table will be available thru that property.